# Why is my dropdown list showing differently on phone than desktop and how can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a normal select/option setup for a dropdown list and on desktop it looks like normal:

[image]

However, on the phone it instead uses some native phone list, something that looks like this:

[image]

This could be all fine, the problem is that in some places I have made my own multi select dropdown list which looks like this:

[image]

This list will show like this on both desktop and phone, since it is just made up of divs.

**Questions**

1. Can I somehow force all devices to use the same type of dropdown on a normal select/option setup?
2. Should I?
3. If not, would you recommend me to create my own dropdown lists too so that I get the same behaviour for both normal and multiple select dropdown lists? It is sort of ugle when one dropdown shows as e.g. native android and one as a "normal" dropdown on the phone.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: 1. No, 3. Either that, or use the normal, native select for your multiple selection needs as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `<Select>` is a native component.

### What is a native component?

A native component is an HTML element that uses shadow containers to add native OS components to an HTML site. Rather than the browser drawing the entire element, it relies on the operating system to do this. Elements like `<button>`, `<a>`, `<div>`, `<span>`, any many more will have their own drawing process. A `<select>` element, however, uses whatever the operating system provides. Any styling capabilities are very limited.

Technically, a web browser could implement their own "drawing" of a `<select>` element, but this is not worth the effort because most people create their own dropdown components. The `<select>` element really just exists to provide *something* for developers to use – think a quick small micro-application.

Although you may be able to add most CSS styles to the "button" part of the select element, you cannot to the dropdown. The dropdown is not the `<option>` tags, but rather still a part of the `<select>` element. This is because the option tags just provide information to the select component about which options to show (they are just data containers). The dropdown is 100% native and cannot be styled.

### Can you force all devices to use the same dropdown?

**No**. This is impossible. Each web browser has their own implementation on how to handle the `<select>` element. Firefox draws their own dropdowns. Safari and Chrome use the native macOS/Windows/Linux/iOS/Android dropdowns. These are not configurable and you are at the mercy of the OS/firefox.

### Should you force all devices to use the same dropdown?

**Yes**. The way you would accomplish this, is by using the custom component method. You will have to implement your own dropdown. Most sites do this to provide a uniform user interface and experience.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer, I think I will have to create my own style then. I just don't get WHY the select should be different, why not at least have an attribute option to set if you want the native one instead of your own, e.g. "native-mode="true""

Comment: Web browsers do this because most people only want to style the actual "button" that trigger the dropdown. A lot of developers and organizations don't care how the dropdown looks (think android vs iOS). The OS provides a very stable component that is compatible with the device size (think iOS select menus vs desktop). It makes no sense for a browser to give styling options for dropdowns since it takes very little css to create your own customized dropdown compoents